# Some markers wont go away in Google Maps using iOS and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, swift3

I hope someone can help me find this out, I have this problem since yesterday and have been searching what could be wrong, maybe I missed something? I'm new (about 2 months using a mac) to iOS and Swift and the whole mac ecosystem in general.

The thing is that I'm migrating to native iOS an Phonegap app that relies on a lot of markers (about 300 to 400, and lags a lot) that some of them can be disabled by the user(by groups), the problem comes when deleting the markers some of them remain like ghosts, their map property is set to nil, and no touch event is triggered(I've got them set to perform a segue)

Here is the code that I use to store the objects, and then to delete them, currently I'm using a dictionary with arrays to determine which markers to delete.

I translated the comments because they are in Spanish so you can have an idea of what i'm doing (or trying to do) in short terms.

Here is the code where I add the markers, also I know that there might be some better ways to do some things like

```
//parses some data, and retrieves some more to create the markers
func procesaMarcadores(retorno: [String:Any]) {

    //skiped a lot of previous code

    if let servicios = retorno["servicios"] as? NSArray {

        //a simple cycle to iterate through data recieved
        for item in servicios {
            let items = item as! NSDictionary

            //lazy, easy, and dirty way to retrieve latitude and longitude, must change
            let latitud = (items["direccion_georeferenciada_latitud"] as! NSString).doubleValue
            let longitud = (items["direccion_georeferenciada_longitud"] as! NSString).doubleValue
            let foto = self.urlFotos + String((items["foto"] as! NSString))

            //new marker                
            let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitud, longitude: longitud)
            marker.userData = foto //a simple string with a url to use latter in the next view

            //setting mapView in main thread just for safety?, don't wanna mess something
            DispatchQueue.main.async(){
                marker.map = self.mapView
            }

            marker.icon = imagenChica //custom marker image

            //storing the objects in dictionary
            let tipo = items["id_tipo_servicio"] as! Int
            var arregloServicios = dicServicios[tipo] ?? []
            arregloServicios.append(marker)
            dicServicios[tipo] = arregloServicios
        }
    }
}
```

Here I delete the markers

```
//updates markers, gets new data for markers, and deletes markers
func actualizaMarcadores(marcadores: [Any]?, seleccionado: Int, perfil: Int?){

//lots of deleted code

//deletes markers group if variable noSale is set to delete markers of the group of the variable seleccionado
    if noSale {
        //asynchronous delete just to be safe?
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //whiping markers from mapView
            var arregloServicios = self.dicServicios[seleccionado]
            for i in arregloServicios! {
                i.map = nil
            }
            //releasing a bit of memory
            self.dicServicios[seleccionado] = nil
            //already tried not deleting the marker objects
        }
    }
}
```

I have googled for the answer and I have been researching and found nothing relevant, other than that some years ago, in an old google maps api had a bug, but it was fixed, also searched in the documentation but the only thing I found was that the other way to delete markers is with `mapView.clear()` but then i would have to reassign all the markers and the cpu goes to about 60% and thats worst than about 5% cpu usage with some poorly coded ways to cast string to int.

Comment: Hi @zxinik, can you reduce the problem down into a piece of code that others can test on their machines? It's difficult to see exactly what is going on here from the code snippets you've posted.

Comment: Your English is fine, but please get into the habit of starting sentences with capitals, and expressing the personal pronoun "I" as a capital. Fairly or otherwise, posts may be downvoted here if they look like they are written in a rush, or on a mobile phone where capitals are "too hard" to type.

Comment: just get the maker inside for loop, and set the `maker = nill` for  delete the maker

Comment: @paulvs today I'll try to post a working snippet with the same problem

Comment: @halfer thanks I'll make sure to get the habit of capitalizing everiting that has to

Comment: @amirt I already tried that too, and in the documentation it says that the way to do it is simply removing the map reference from the marker [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#remove_a_marker)

Answer (score 0):

**Here I give you just overview you can cross check it with your existing code**

```
import GoogleMaps
var arrayMarkerObj = [String:GMSMarker]() //Use dictionary
var driverMarker:GMSMarker! //Define it as gloabal
class markerController:UIViewController{

    func procesaMarcadores(retorno: [String:Any]) {

        //skiped a lot of previous code

        if let servicios = retorno["servicios"] as? NSArray {

            //a simple cycle to iterate through data recieved
            for item in servicios {
                let items = item as! NSDictionary

                //lazy, easy, and dirty way to retrieve latitude and longitude, must change
                let latitud = (items["direccion_georeferenciada_latitud"] as! NSString).doubleValue
                let longitud = (items["direccion_georeferenciada_longitud"] as! NSString).doubleValue
                let foto = self.urlFotos + String((items["foto"] as! NSString))

                //new marker

                 let positionDriver = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude: latitud, longitude: longitud)
                var marker:GMSMarker! = GMSMarker(position: positionDriver)
                marker.userData = foto //a simple string with a url to use latter in the next view

                //setting mapView in main thread just for safety?, don't wanna mess something
//                DispatchQueue.main.async(){
//                    marker.map = self.mapView
//                }

                marker.icon = imagenChica //custom marker image
                    marker.map = self.mapView
                 self.arrayMarkerObj.updateValue(marker, forKey: key) //Put some uniqe KEY which define marker location
                 self.animateMarker(objMarker: marker, locations: positionDriver)
                //storing the objects in dictionary
//                let tipo = items["id_tipo_servicio"] as! Int
//                var arregloServicios = dicServicios[tipo] ?? []
//                arregloServicios.append(marker)
//                dicServicios[tipo] = arregloServicios
            }
        }
    }

    func animateMarker(objMarker:GMSMarker,locations:CLLocationCoordinate2D){

        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(2.0)
        objMarker.position = locations
        CATransaction.commit()

    }
//Delete Marker
func deleteMark(){
     for(key, value) in self.arrayMarkerObj{
         self.driverMarker = self.arrayMarkerObj[key!]

                if(self.driverMarker != nil){
                    self.driverMarker.map = nil
                    self.arrayMarkerObj.removeValue(forKey: key!)

                }

          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check if it will work your way, I'll let you know as soon as i can